# How to disabled buttons using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have two functions in PROC.CTRL editProcessRating function i am disabling save button until user answer all question , i have view function(viewProcessRating) so on this function i want to disable save as draft and save both buttons permanently. 
How i can achieve this task using AngularJS disable functionality ?

Code so far tried below....

HTML

```
<div class="spaceonBottom text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="handleCancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="disableDraft" ng-click="savePRTDraft()" ng-show="showSaveDraftBtn">Save
        as Draft</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
        ng-disabled="disableSubmitButton" ng-click="submitClicked()">Submit</button>

</div>
```

KENDOGRID.JS

```
{
                  field: '',
                  title: 'Action',
                  width: '8em',
                  template:'<a href="" ng-click=\'viewProcessRating(this.dataItem.processRatingSessionKey)\' <span ng-if="this.dataItem.viewable" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" ng-click=\'editProcessRating(this.dataItem.processRatingSessionKey)\' <span ng-if=" this.dataItem.editable "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </span></a>'

              },
```

Proc.Ctrl

```
$scope.editProcessRating = function(prcsSessionKey) {
        var prtUrl = "/getProcessRating/"+prcsSessionKey;
        $location.path(prtUrl);
    }

    $scope.viewProcessRating = function(prcsSessionKey) {
      var prtUrl = "/getProcessRating/"+prcsSessionKey;
      $scope.disableDraft = true;
      $location.path(prtUrl);
    }
```

RAT.CTRL

```
 $scope.disableSubmitButton = true;  //the submit button is disabled until user answers all 12 questions

$scope.calculateTotal = function(value){
        var total = 0;
        var findRatingKey = {};

        $scope.questionSelected[value] = true;
        for( i=0; i< $scope.questionnaire.length; i++)
        {
            total = total + $scope.ratingQstnResult.ratingSelect[i+1];
        }
        $scope.ratingQstnResult.rtgTotalScore = total;

        //If the answer to first question is High, system recommendation should be High
        if($scope.ratingQstnResult.ratingSelect[1] === 5){
            $scope.ratingQstnResult.sysRecomm = 'High';
            findRatingKey = $filter('filter')($scope.decisionList, {text:'High'});
        }else if(total < 28 ){
            $scope.ratingQstnResult.sysRecomm = 'Low';
            findRatingKey = $filter('filter')($scope.decisionList, {text:'Low'});
        } else if((total >= 28) && (total < 40)){
            $scope.ratingQstnResult.sysRecomm = 'Moderate';
            findRatingKey = $filter('filter')($scope.decisionList, {text:'Moderate'});
        } else{
            $scope.ratingQstnResult.sysRecomm = 'High';
            findRatingKey = $filter('filter')($scope.decisionList, {text:'High'});
        };
        if((!processPromiseObj.data.prQuestionnaireDTOList) || (processPromiseObj.data.sessionStatusLookUpCode === 'RA_PRT_IN_PROG')){
            $scope.ratingQstnResult.computerGeneRatingKey = findRatingKey[0].id;
            $scope.ratingQstnResult.busDecision = findRatingKey[0].id;

            for(j=1; j<= $scope.questionnaire.length; j++ ){
                if(!$scope.questionSelected[j]){
                    //console.log('there is one not selected');
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(j > $scope.questionnaire.length){
                $scope.disableSubmitButton = false;
                $scope.showBusDecDropDown = true;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: So, is the problem that it is not being enabled after the user answers the questions? Or does the button never disable?

Comment: Save button is being enabled after user answered, Edit is good but on View i want to disabled both buttons save and save as draft permanently because its just a view.

Comment: Put `$scope.disableSubmitButton=true` in `viewProcessRating` method?

Comment: i tried that its not working.. here is the problem , because questions are not completed yet so on View Save is already disabled till all question get answered but i want different approach on View i want to disable both buttons in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `j` will ever be greater than `$scope.questionnaire.length`. Use `j == $scope.questionnaire.length` instead:

```
        if (j == $scope.questionnaire.length) {
            $scope.disableSubmitButton = false;
            $scope.showBusDecDropDown = true;
        }
```

Comment: Edit is working good once all questioner are answered save button is being enabled but  i have problem disabling buttons on view function